# Appending from an ArrayList more than once causes multiple values to be printed at once?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, arraylist, append

I've run into a problem that I'm not sure how to fix. I'm working on a character creator that writes to a .txt file and reads from the same .txt file. I'm able to append each line from the .txt file to a JTextArea on the first try, however when I return to the main menu, and then proceed back to the view tab, it displays the first two values instead of just the first value. With every return it adds another value. Any ideas on how to fix? My apologies if this is a really dumb question.

```
viewInfo.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
        {

            i3 = i3 + 1;    

            try { BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("charCreator.txt"));

                while ((name1 [i3] = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    if (!list.contains(name1 [i3])){  

                        list.add (name1 [i3]);

                    }

                }

                br.close ();                  

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            String infoArray [] = list.toArray (new String [500]);

            viewArea.append (infoArray [i3]);
            viewArea.append ("\n");

        } 
    }
    );
```

I'm not entirely confident in my coding skills yet so constructive criticism is always appreciated. Most variables are global.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to ensure you don't keep your list around when you enter the method. Something like:

```
list.clear()
```

The other way to do it, is to move the list declaration into your method, so you know it's new.  It doesn't look like you need it after the method is over.

Comment: I've tried your suggestions. I'm still getting the same problems. Instead of giving me name1 [1] only, it gives me name1 [1] & name1 [2] when I only need the former. This only happens on the second attempt at viewing entries.

Comment: There is not enough code to understand what is going on.  Maybe something is writing to the file unexpectedly?

Comment: Perhaps I'm writing to the file strangely? Writing to .txt file code --> http://prntscr.com/gu85tw